# Find string in documents lines and then take the value from one of lines before

Tags: python, string, text-files

I am reading a text file similar to this:

```
...
#9 1.11 2.22
#10 3.33 4.44
#11 5.55 6.66
#12 7.77 8.88
#13 6.999 0.189
...
```

In which certain lines might be there or might not, e.g. from line `#13` on.
What I'd like to do is to test the text file for this condition, and if it is verified, take the value from one of the previous lines (not just the line before), say #9:

```
for test in open('example.txt'):
    line = test.split()
    if test.find("#13") != -1:
        collect.append(line[1]) # <-- here should be the value from the line starting with "#9"
```

What is the most appropriate way to do this in python?

Comment: Depends on the size of files. You can `readlines` and then you have access to the previous line easily. Or you read the file line-by-line and "remember" the previous line in a variable

Comment: Do you always know ahead of time which line the test is on and which line to take the value from (lines 13 and 9 in your example)?  Or do you need to test each line and then take the value from a previous line (in the example, line 13 passed the test and you need data from 4 lines earlier)?

Comment: @JanStránský files are small. about ~20 lines each. I thought about the extra variable, but I thought there might be a "better" way.

Comment: @RootTwo it depends. If the files has the `#13` line, then there are a given number of lines (always the same). Otherwise the number is different, but always the same.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why `#13` will need the line with `#9` in your example, but according to what you described, you can go with an extra variable to keep track of the previous line:

```
prevline = []
for test in open('example.txt'):
    line = test.split()
    if test.find("#13") != -1:
        collect.append(prevline[1])
    prevline = line
```

Comment: Thanks. Because the very existence of `#13` implies that the value written in the line starting with `#9` is trustable. Anyway, it is the input from *a* previous line that I need, not THE previous line. I might have used a wrong word but this is well shown in the text file example reported in the original post.

Answer (score 0):

```
collect = []
with open("example.txt") as file:
    prevLine = file[0]
    for line in file[1:]:
        if "#13" in line:
            collect.append(prevLine.split(" ")[1:])
        prevLine = line
```

This opens the file and reads through all of the lines.  When it finds the line that contains `"#13"` it adds all of the numbers to the list `collect` that appear after the label (# + a number) on the line before.  If `"#13"` is not in the line, it stores that line as the previous  line.

Comment: Please add an explanation with your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Given that the files are small (20 or so lines), just read the whole file using `readlines()`:

```
with open(filename, 'rt') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()          # this keeps the \n on each line
```

or `read()` and `splitlines()`:

```
with open(filename, 'rt') as f:
    lines = f.read().splitlines()  # this strips trailing whitespace on each line
```

Then do the test are return the appropriate lines:

```
if '#13' in lines[12]:
    do something

else:
    do something else
```

Comment: Thanks. Can you be more specific in how I would collect the values from lines starting with `#9` in your code? (that would be the `collect.append(line[1])` from my original post).

Comment: Just change the test: `if len(lines) >= 12 and '#13' in lines[12]`.  Or whatever the test needs to be for your use case.

Comment: The question doesn't really say what to do with the values.  So I said 'do something'.  You could append them to a list, or something else.

Comment: It says it. I have to collect those values in a list